# Bounding sum of norms by the sum of sqaure of norms

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, normed-spaces

How can you bound sum of norms (e.g. sum of norms of vectors) by sum of square of the same norms?

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean $$\sum_{j=1}^n \|x_i\| \le n^{1/2} \left(\sum_{j=1}^n \|x_i\|^2\right)^{1/2}$$
which comes from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Is there a tighter bound?

Comment: It is an equality if all $\|x_i\|$ are equal.

Comment: Does this work for every root?

Comment: Hölder's inequality says $\sum_{j=1}^n \|x_i\| \le n^{1/p} \left(\sum_{j=1}^n \|x_i\|^q\right)^{1/q}$ if $1/p + 1/q = 1$, $p,q > 1$.